# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'nearestColor') at nearestColor.js:400:26 at nearestColor.js:403:2

Tags: javascript, module

Im trying to import 'nearestColor' from this module 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/dtao/nearest-color@master/nearestColor.js' in my javascript file but it keeps giving me this error.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'nearestColor')
at nearestColor.js: 400:26
at nearestColor.js: 403:2

```
if (typeof module === 'object' && module && module.exports) {
    module.exports = nearestColor;
  } else {
    context.nearestColor = nearestColor;
  }

}(this));
export default nearestColor;
```

I tried removing the else statement but it gave me this error instead
Uncaught ReferenceError: nearestColor is not defined
at nearestColor.js:401:16

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Where does this `export default nearestColor;` came from? It's not in the library. Can you show your code for importing the module?

Comment: I added `export default nearestColor` because it kept showing me this error if I don't "Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './nearestColor.js' does not provide an export named 'default'". This is how I import the module in my js file, `import nearestColor from './nearestColor.js';`

Comment: and this is in my html `<script type="module" src="./nearestColor.js"></script>`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.